# Solicitud de Ajax sin respuesta o bloqueado

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Mi aplicación esta presentando lo siguiente al realizar solicitudes de Ajax con jQuery: en un hosting hay solicitudes que si me funcionan pero otras no, estuve revisando y al parecer esta todo correcto, solo veo algo diferente que en el debug de una solicitud veo que en el apartado de tiempos dice bloqueado en color rojo, no se si esto es cuestión de mi proveedor o es en el código.

Estoy trabajando con JavaScript y PHP, ya hice cambios con fetch, Ajax y post jQuery, pero no me devuelve los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En respuesta a  @Bayron Vazquez iba a agregar el código, pero en comentarios no me permite, lo hare aquí en respuesta:

**PHP servidor:**

```
switch($op)
{
  case 'consultaproductos':

    $queryproductos = "SELECT * FROM prodcutos ORDER BY id_producto";
    $resultproductos = mysqli_query($conexion,$queryproductos);
    
    if(!$resultproductos){
        printf("Ha ocurrido un error",mysqli_error($conexion)); 
    }
    $row_productos = mysqli_num_rows($resultproductos);
  
    if($row_productos <=0)
    {
        $messagproducto = "No hay registros";

        $jsonmsjp = array();
        $jsonmsjp[]=array(
             $messagproducto 
        );
        echo json_encode($messagproducto);

    }
    else
    {
        $jsonproductos = array();
        while($filaproductos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultclientes)){
            $jsonproductos[]=array(
                'id_cliente'=> $filaproductos['id_cliente'],
                'nombre_abreviado'=> $filaproductos['nombre_abreviado'], 
                'nombre_cliente'=> $filaproductos['nombre_cliente'],
                'direccion'=> $filaproductos['direccion'], 
                'telefono'=> $filaproductos['telefono'],
                'estatus'=> $filaproductos['estatus'],  
 
            );
        }  
        $jsonstring_productos = json_encode($jsonproductos);
        echo $jsonstring_productos; 
        print_r($jsonstring_clientes); 
    } 
  break;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://host/querys/consultaproductos.php',
type:'POST', 
data:{peticion:'consultaproductos'},
})
.done(function(infoproductos){ 
  console.log(infoproductos);
   if(infoproductos.length>0){ 
    datosproductos =[];
    datosproductos = infoproductos;
   
     tablacontrolesproductos(); 
   }
   else{
     $("#rowsproductos").html('No hay registros');
   }  
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  /*var test = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
  var test2 = $.parseJSON(test.d);
  alert(test2[0].Name); */

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) { 
    console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.'); 
  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) { 
    console.log('Requested page not found [404]');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    console.log('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    console.log('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }
});
```

El error que me devuelve es:

> Requested JSON parse failed."

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero cuando dice bloqueada es porque tu recurso está esperando algún evento o que cargue ciertos elementos del DOM para poder ejecutarse y por eso aparece así

Comment: Muestra el codigo que hace la peticion y el codigo que responde en el serve, es muy complicado dar una respuesta sin ver el codigo.

Answer (score 2):

La solicitud para la que muestras el análisis de tiempos, de hecho, es respondida por el servidor.

## Tiempo de bloqueo

De acuerdo a [la respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24449324/255257) en la pregunta *My http request block,what 's wrong* en StackOverfow en inglés, que a su vez trae la información de un hilo en los foros de google (que ya no existen):

> The 'Blocked' time is the delta between the 'requestTime' and the 'startTime'. Basically, this is a measure of the amount of time between the UI thread initiating the request for the network resource and the HTTP GET for the request bits getting onto the wire. In between, there can be internal queuing/message passing delay, cache lookup, dns resolution, and TCP connection setup.

Mi traducción libre sería:

> El tiempo 'Bloqueado' es el delta entre el la hora de la petición y la hora de inicio. Básicamente, esta es una medida de la cantidad de tiempo transcurrido entre el hilo de la interfaz de usuario iniciando la solicitud por el recurso de la red y que los primeros bits de la solicitud HTTP GET lleguen al cable. En el medio, puede haber una cola interna/retraso en el paso de mensajes, búsqueda en caché, resolución de DNS y configuración de conexión TCP.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> no se si esto es cuestión de mi proveedor o es en el código?

Es normal que ocurra un tiempo de bloqueo en todas las peticiones, **no significa que la petición haya sido bloqueada** y no tiene nada que ver con tu *proveedor* o con el código que prepara la petición.

El nombre puede venir de que el hilo se encuentra bloqueado, es un término común en programación multihilos y se da generalmente cuándo un hilo está esperando a que se complete una operación o a obtener respuesta de otro hilo.

En este caso particular, ese bloqueo puede tener muchos motivos, uno que se resalta con frecuencia es una lenta resolución DNS, pero no parece ser tu caso. En general, 53 milisegundos no parece un tiempo muy alto, tomando en cuenta que hay una serie de operaciones que ocurren tras bambalinas. Crear un nuevo hilo, lanzar su ejecución y preparar en este los artefactos necesarios para manejar el socket de conexión, suelen tomar un tiempo que bien justifica esos 53 ms.

Además, puede haber muchas otras razones, incluso saturación de recursos del equipo dónde se ejecuta el proceso o del propio navegador, además que este puede aplicar una espera si hay varias peticiones concurrentes, sobre todo si hay varias al mismo dominio.

Diría que tampoco tiene que ver con tu código directamente, pues ese tiempo se comienza a medir cuándo lanzas la petición en el hilo principal, es decir, cuándo se invoca el método `send()` del objeto `XMLHttpRequest`.

Lo que tu código se tarde en preparar la petición no va en esa cuenta de tiempo.

## Solicitudes que funcionan y otras no

Tu pregunta ya está respondida, ahora sobre tu comentario que tienes solicitudes que no funcionan, bueno, es difícil decir que pueda estar pasando con la información que das pero, de entrada, si ocurre un error en las comunicaciones, la línea de tiempo luciría diferente, pues la petición no se completaría.

Si ocurriera un error en la petición como tal, esta se completaría, pero tendrías un código de error de parte del servidor. Si es un buen ciudadano, un status distinto de 200 es lo estándar.

Si no lo es, puedes obtener un 200, pero un mensaje o estructura de error en lugar del contenido normal.

Sospecho que, dado que no mencionas ningún error, la petición si se esté completando y tienes un status 200, lo que me haría ir a revisar qué está ocurriendo del lado del servidor, ya que el problema no parece estar del lado del cliente.

Repito, ese análisis es por lo que mencionas en la pregunta. Si estás obviando información importante, va a ser incorrecto.

Answer (score -1):

Me lleve un día y medio en encontrar el error me estaba volviendo loco, al debugear el código en el lado del servidor PHP todo estaba correcto pero hubo algo que me llamo la atención en una tabla unos registros tenían la tilde en la ñ se las quite y se resolvió el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto es la solucion a que problema?